# Probability Expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

Estimate the expected number of integers with 1000 digits that need to be selected at random to find a prime if the probability a number with 1000 digits is prime is 1/2302?

Comment: Expectation of [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of integers needed to select a prime, $X$, is geometrically distributed with $p = 1/2302$. The probability of the event $\{X = k\}$ is equal to $\mathbb{P}(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$ for $k \geq 0$. Its mean is
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\mathbb{P}(X=k) = \frac{1}{p}
\end{align}
So for finding a prime number when drawing integers with 1000 digits we would expectedly need $2302$ draws.

Comment: Where does $2302$ come from ?!

Comment: @Furrane are you messing with me or what.

Comment: woops didn't see it in the OP's post, sorry.